# customizing folding markers via user settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been using code folding in vim using the kent extensions that allow for folds to be specified in any language using {{{ and }}} markers. For example, OCaml I would say:

```
(* {{{ comment *)

code

(* }}} *)
```

and in LaTeX I might say:

```
% {{{ name

text

% }}}
```

The vim folding looks for the {{{ }}} pairs as the start/end markers for a fold.  I found some examples of specifying custom folding markers as part of creating a brand new language extension in VSCode, but I haven't been able to figure out how to add the {{{ and }}} markers as part of my user settings.  I'd prefer to not have to modify existing extensions to use these style markers.

I'm working with a large code base that already makes extensive use of these folding markers, and for the time being I end up being in vim if I want to take advantage of them.  I'd really like to be able to move to vscode more, but the lack of this folding mechanism is blocking me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find [this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12146#issuecomment-332005485) and [this feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/36002) relevant.

Essentially, each language has specific markers supported. However, it sounds like there's a good chance that configurable markers will be implemented sometime in the future.

The [Explicit Folding](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zokugun.explicit-folding) extension appears to be exactly what you're looking for, but it's experimental and has known issues.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the new zokugun-folding extension - that solved it exactly, and by coincidence had been released just a few days ago.  It had a bug in configuring it, but the author responded to the issue and the current version seems to work just fine.